# targeting jquery ui buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am trying to change the jquery mobile ui button class into a plus sign. What I have used below.

New code trying to use:

```
$('[id*=new] span.ui-btn-inner').removeClass('ui-btn-inner').addClass('ui-icon-plus');
```

Below is the current code --

```
<td align="left">

<a href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'$IF$new$0$$0');" tabindex="51" id="$IF$new$0$$0" name="$IF$new$0$$0" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-c" style="padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px;" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c"><span class="ui-btn-inner">
<span class="ui-btn-text">Add</span></span></a>
</td>
```

Comment: You should put your code in the question, not in the comments. Code is difficult to read in comments and they weren't designed for it. Also, what is your question? Are you getting errors? Is there some unexpected side-effect of your code. Explain what went wrong.

Comment: If you type `$('[id*=new] span.ui-btn-inner')` in the console, do you see your span?

Comment: Yes I do see the span. Code works in the console. expect when I combine with script with pageinit.

Comment: I had inserted the code in the question section - but it was deleted for some reason. No errors in the console. Code is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the class `ui-btn-icon-notext` to the button to have it hide the text, then add another span to `ui-btn-inner` for the icon:

```
    $("[id*=new]").addClass("ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext");
    $("[id*=new]").find(".ui-btn-inner").append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus ui-icon-shadow"&nbsp;></span>');
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/wh1mstv0/)**

Click the Change to Icon button in the demo to see it change.